# Return one single row with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query, I am wanting to group all accounting data together and GROUP_CONCAT the clients site names and site IP's.

I have used `GROUP_CONCAT(site_name) as site_name` and `GROUP_CONCAT(site_ip) as site_ip` but the results I get are still incorrect and I am getting duplicate IP's in the GROUP_CONCAT column.

I need a single row of data per client with the accounted traffic SUM/Grouped together for each of the site IP's belonging to them.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, 
SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes, 
SUM(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes, 
package_id, 
username, 
userid, 
networkaccess, 
packagename, 
speedlimit, 
threshold, 
throttlelimit, 
extendeddata, 
datalimitamount, 
accountingdays, 
GROUP_CONCAT(site_name) as site_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(site_ip) as site_ip 
FROM 
(
    (
        SELECT 
            ip_accounting.src_address as site_ip, 
            SUM(ip_accounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes, 
            0 as download_bytes, 
            clients.username, 
            clients.userid, 
            clients.networkaccess, 
            clients.extendeddata, 
            data_packages.package_id, 
            data_packages.packagename, 
            data_packages.speedlimit, 
            data_packages.threshold, 
            data_packages.throttlelimit, 
            data_packages.datalimitamount, 
            data_packages.accountingdays, 
            client_site_ip.site_name 
        FROM 
            ip_accounting 
            join client_site_ip on client_site_ip.site_ip = ip_accounting.src_address 
            JOIN clients ON client_site_ip.userid = clients.userid 
            join data_packages on data_packages.package_id = clients.datapackage 
        WHERE 
            dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') 
            AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
            and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
                CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
                INTERVAL data_packages.accountingdays DAY
            ) 
            AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
        GROUP BY 
            src_address
    ) 
    UNION ALL 
        (
            SELECT 
                ip_accounting.dst_address as site_ip, 
                0 AS upload_bytes, 
                SUM(ip_accounting.bytes) as download_bytes, 
                clients.username, 
                clients.userid, 
                clients.networkaccess, 
                clients.extendeddata, 
                data_packages.package_id, 
                data_packages.packagename, 
                data_packages.speedlimit, 
                data_packages.threshold, 
                data_packages.throttlelimit, 
                data_packages.datalimitamount, 
                data_packages.accountingdays, 
                client_site_ip.site_name 
            FROM 
                ip_accounting 
                join client_site_ip on client_site_ip.site_ip = ip_accounting.dst_address 
                JOIN clients ON client_site_ip.userid = clients.userid 
                join data_packages on data_packages.package_id = clients.datapackage 
            WHERE 
                src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') 
                AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
                and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
                    INTERVAL data_packages.accountingdays DAY
                ) 
                AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
            GROUP BY 
                dst_address
        )
) a 
GROUP BY 
site_ip 
ORDER BY 
INET_ATON(site_ip)
```

My current result looks like:

[image][image]

Comment: I can see you don't understand GROUP BY... Because you misuse MySQL's GROUP BY method what will give you invalid results.. i advice you to read this ( https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ )  p.s old article but it's still valid up to day.

Comment: I'm a bit confused even more now. If I remove the GROUP_CONCAT, everything works correctly but then returns multiple rows with the same data per client but with the different site information such as bandwidth usage, site name, site IP and so on. All I am wanting to do is to merge the rows and give me commas for the `site_name` and `site_ip` columns with the sum of all the bandwidth usage per site belonging to each client. If you say that I am using GROUP BY incorrectly then can you tell me what I should do please

Comment: "If you say that I am using GROUP BY incorrectly then can you tell me what I should do please " That is hard to say without example data and expected output..

Comment: I have just said what my expected output needs to be: All I am wanting to do is to merge the rows and give me commas for the site_name and site_ip columns with the sum of all the bandwidth usage per site belonging to each client

Comment: But still you will get better help when you provide example data.. We are not here to reverse engineer your SQL query.

Comment: FWIW, I've not yet encountered a problem where GROUP_CONCAT was required. I doubt that it's required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should group by the non aggregated columns  (and not for the column you use in aggregation function) eg:

```
  SELECT 
  SUM(upload_bytes) as upload_bytes, 
  SUM(download_bytes) as download_bytes, 
  SUM(upload_bytes + download_bytes) as totalbytes, 
  package_id, 
  username, 
  userid, 
  networkaccess, 
  packagename, 
  speedlimit, 
  threshold, 
  throttlelimit, 
  extendeddata, 
  datalimitamount, 
  accountingdays, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT site_name) as site_name, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT site_ip) as site_ip 
  FROM 
  (
      (
          SELECT 
              ip_accounting.src_address as site_ip, 
              SUM(ip_accounting.bytes) AS upload_bytes, 
              0 as download_bytes, 
              clients.username, 
              clients.userid, 
              clients.networkaccess, 
              clients.extendeddata, 
              data_packages.package_id, 
              data_packages.packagename, 
              data_packages.speedlimit, 
              data_packages.threshold, 
              data_packages.throttlelimit, 
              data_packages.datalimitamount, 
              data_packages.accountingdays, 
              client_site_ip.site_name 
          FROM 
              ip_accounting 
              join client_site_ip on client_site_ip.site_ip = ip_accounting.src_address 
              JOIN clients ON client_site_ip.userid = clients.userid 
              join data_packages on data_packages.package_id = clients.datapackage 
          WHERE 
              dst_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') 
              AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
              and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
                  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
                  INTERVAL data_packages.accountingdays DAY
              ) 
              AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
          GROUP BY 
              src_address
      ) 
      UNION ALL 
          (
              SELECT 
                  ip_accounting.dst_address as site_ip, 
                  0 AS upload_bytes, 
                  SUM(ip_accounting.bytes) as download_bytes, 
                  clients.username, 
                  clients.userid, 
                  clients.networkaccess, 
                  clients.extendeddata, 
                  data_packages.package_id, 
                  data_packages.packagename, 
                  data_packages.speedlimit, 
                  data_packages.threshold, 
                  data_packages.throttlelimit, 
                  data_packages.datalimitamount, 
                  data_packages.accountingdays, 
                  client_site_ip.site_name 
              FROM 
                  ip_accounting 
                  join client_site_ip on client_site_ip.site_ip = ip_accounting.dst_address 
                  JOIN clients ON client_site_ip.userid = clients.userid 
                  join data_packages on data_packages.package_id = clients.datapackage 
              WHERE 
                  src_address NOT BETWEEN INET_NTOA('192.168.0.1') 
                  AND INET_NTOA('192.168.255.254') 
                  and timeanddate BETWEEN SUBDATE(
                      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 
                      INTERVAL data_packages.accountingdays DAY
                  ) 
                  AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() 
              GROUP BY 
                  dst_address
          )
  ) a 
  GROUP BY 
      package_id, 
      username, 
      userid, 
      networkaccess, 
      packagename, 
      speedlimit, 
      threshold, 
      throttlelimit, 
      extendeddata, 
      datalimitamount, 
      accountingdays
```

Comment: I am still getting duplicate `site_names` and `site_ips` in the results

Comment: "I am still getting duplicate site_names and site_ips in the results" You can use DISTINCT in the function GROUP_CONCAT..  like so `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT site_names) AS  site_name`